# How to define a single function to sum and select data based on multiple conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, function, user-defined-functions

I wrote some lines of code to get 3 types of scores (3 columns) based on 2 different conditions. I've pasted my code below. The output is 3 different columns based on a document-score for each of the 5 companies. Now, these lines of code work but I want to define a function to do the same thing for each corresponding row. 
I want it so that if I were to add more data to the main dataset, the function would automatically select the summed corresponding values for any new data.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
#Article scores

amazon_article_score = keywords.loc[(keywords['Company'] == 'amazon') & 
(keywords['DocumentType'] == 'article'),'Polarity'].sum()
keydata.loc[keydata.index[0], 'ArticleScore'] = amazon_article_score

boeing_article_score = keywords.loc[(keywords['Company'] == 'boeing') &
(keywords['DocumentType'] == 'article'), 'Polarity'].sum()
keydata.loc[keydata.index[1], 'ArticleScore'] = boeing_article_score

target_article_score = keywords.loc[(keywords['Company'] == 'target') &
(keywords['DocumentType'] == 'article'), 'Polarity'].sum()
keydata.loc[keydata.index[2], 'ArticleScore'] = target_article_score

tesla_article_score = keywords.loc[(keywords['Company'] == 'tesla') &
(keywords['DocumentType'] == 'article'),'Polarity'].sum()
keydata.loc[keydata.index[3], 'ArticleScore'] = tesla_article_score

walmart_article_score = keywords.loc[(keywords['Company'] == 'walmart') &
(keywords['DocumentType'] == 'article'), 'Polarity'].sum()
keydata.loc[keydata.index[4], 'ArticleScore'] = walmart_article_score

#Blog scores
amazon_blog_score = keywords.loc[(keywords['Company'] == 'amazon') &
(keywords['DocumentType'] == 'blog'), 'Polarity'].sum()
keydata.loc[keydata.index[0], 'BlogScore'] = amazon_blog_score

boeing_blog_score = keywords.loc[(keywords['Company'] == 'boeing') &
(keywords['DocumentType'] == 'blog'), 'Polarity'].sum()
keydata.loc[keydata.index[1], 'BlogScore'] = boeing_blog_score

target_blog_score = keywords.loc[(keywords['Company'] == 'target') &
(keywords['DocumentType'] == 'blog'), 'Polarity'].sum()
keydata.loc[keydata.index[2], 'BlogScore'] = target_blog_score

tesla_blog_score = keywords.loc[(keywords['Company'] == 'tesla') &
(keywords['DocumentType'] == 'blog'), 'Polarity'].sum()
keydata.loc[keydata.index[3], 'BlogScore'] = tesla_blog_score

walmart_blog_score = keywords.loc[(keywords['Company'] == 'walmart') &
(keywords['DocumentType'] == 'blog'), 'Polarity'].sum()
keydata.loc[keydata.index[4], 'BlogScore'] = walmart_blog_score

#News scores
amazon_news_score = keywords.loc[(keywords['Company'] == 'amazon') &
(keywords['DocumentType'] == 'news'), 'Polarity'].sum()
keydata.loc[keydata.index[0], 'NewsScore'] = amazon_news_score

boeing_news_score = keywords.loc[(keywords['Company'] == 'boeing') &
(keywords['DocumentType'] == 'news'), 'Polarity'].sum()
keydata.loc[keydata.index[1], 'NewsScore'] = boeing_news_score

target_news_score = keywords.loc[(keywords['Company'] == 'target') &
(keywords['DocumentType'] == 'news'), 'Polarity'].sum()
keydata.loc[keydata.index[2], 'NewsScore'] = target_news_score

tesla_news_score = keywords.loc[(keywords['Company'] == 'tesla') &
(keywords['DocumentType'] == 'news'), 'Polarity'].sum()
keydata.loc[keydata.index[3], 'NewsScore'] = tesla_news_score

walmart_news_score = keywords.loc[(keywords['Company'] == 'walmart') &
(keywords['DocumentType'] == 'news'), 'Polarity'].sum()
keydata.loc[keydata.index[4], 'NewsScore'] = walmart_news_score
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep your main dataset as a list and then build one function each, but where that company name comes in, you should instead pull from that list (or other iterable).

You'll run into an issue for storing these values as an object like you do here, so instead you should output your results to a dictionary with keys of `blog_score` `article_score` etc.

Then you should create a function that will add a new company, essentially generating the values into the dictionary. You should also have a function to update your values, if you expect them to change over time.

```py
scores = {}

def add_company(company_name):
    article_score = keywords.loc[(keywords['Company'] == company_name) & (keywords['DocumentType'] == 'article'),'Polarity'].sum() 
    keydata.loc[keydata.index[0], 'ArticleScore'] = article_score

    scores[company_name] = {'article_score'=article_score}
    return
```

With the above example, it's missing a lot of things like checking if that company already exists and instead adding to the dictionary or returning an error, etc. But you should get the basic idea.

**Edit:**
Here is a full version. You need to replace my artificial `companies` with a dynamic way to generate that.

```py
companies = [('amazon',0),('boeing',1),('target',2),('tesla',3),('walmart',4)]

def add_company(company_tuple):
    score_types = [('article','ArticleScore'), 
                   ('blog','BlogScore'), 
                   ('news','NewsScore')]

    # calculate scores
    for type in score_types:
        score = keywords.loc[(keywords['Company'] == company_tuple[0]) & 
        (keywords['DocumentType'] == type[0]),'Polarity'].sum()
        keydata.loc[keydata.index[company_tuple[1]], type[1]] = score
    return

for company in companies:
    add_company(company)
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your help! 

I tried what I understood from your comment and I'm only getting output for the first row. I don't think it's right because I would need to create a loop within the function to iterate over all rows. How can I do that with your function?

Comment: This would only add a single row, correct. So if you want to add a group of rows you would have your company names as an iterable like a list, then do a `for company in companies:` and run the `add_company(company)` function. You would want to add your other score calculations into the same function just like I added `article_score` as well.

Comment: I did exactly that, and now i'm getting the same result for every row. 
Im doing: 

`companies = keydata['Company'].tolist()
scores = {}
def add_company(company_name):
    article_score = keywords.loc[(keywords['Company'] == company_name) & (keywords['DocumentType'] == 'article'),'Polarity'].sum() 
    keydata.loc[keydata.index, 'ArticleScore'] = article_score
    
  blog_score = keywords.loc[(keywords['Company'] == company_name) & (keywords['DocumentType'] == 'blog'),'Polarity'].sum()
    keydata.loc[keydata.index, 'BlogScore'] = blog_score`

(continued in next comment)

Comment: `news_score = keywords.loc[(keywords['Company'] == company_name) & (keywords['DocumentType'] == 'news'),'Polarity'].sum()        
    keydata.loc[keydata.index, 'NewsScore'] = news_score

    scores[company_name] = {'article_score':article_score, 'blog_score': blog_score, 'news_score': news_score}
     
    return

for company in companies:
    add_company(company)`

Comment: If you're getting the same for every row, take a look back and make sure your functions to calculate the scores are correct. I don't have the data you are pulling from or anything else so what I offered in my answer is generic to the problem of how to extract a single function for an iterable of items. You should check to make sure the output of `companies = keydata['Company'].tolist() ` is the expected list of companies which are lower case strings.

Comment: So when I print `scores` I'm getting the right results. So the results are stored in the dictionary. Even `companies` is giving me the right results with all the lower case names. I think there's something wrong with the way I'm looping it, because it gives me the result for only the last element in my list for all the rows.

Comment: `keydata.loc[keydata.index[1]` this part is relevant to the company, so you need to abstract out the index number 1 for each company to be the correct number. You can store the number with companies if you want or retrieve it from your end data location.

Comment: how can I put that in one function? If you see my answer below. That's the code I used. Sorry to keep bothering you, I've just been stuck on this for a while now!

Comment: I edited my answer for you. Let me know if you still don't understand what I did.  Notice I use the indexes for my static lists of tuples to get the info I need so that I'm not writing the same code twice.

Comment: Thank you so much! When you say company_tuple[0] or type[1] are you referring to the list `companies`?

Comment: Yes to the list companies which is a list of tuples with two elements each.

Comment: Thank you so much for that amazing explanation. I was able to get my desired result! I created a list and extended the company names along with the index into the list. It worked like a charm. Thank you so much, again!

Comment: No problem. Please click the check mark next to my answer if it solved it